an isomorphism of the residue class field
I was reading first chapter of Cassel's and Frolich ANT and then I came across the following proposition : $k \cong p^n/p^{n+1}$ of k-modules.
In the first line of the proof it says if $p = R\pi$ then multiplication by $\pi^n$ induces such an isomorphism. I don't get this line. R here is the valuation ring and p, the valuation ideal. Ok so $v(p) = v(R) + v(\pi)$ where I think $\pi$ is an element whose discrete valuation is 1 and R has all elements of valuation 0. So $v(p)>0$ is true.
Then after that how does the valuation v induce the following exact sequence :
$0\rightarrow U\rightarrow K^{*} \rightarrow Z \rightarrow 0$.
Here Ker(v) = $U$ (where v is the second map) but what is the image of U in $K^{*}$ basically how is this map defined? It must be so that the image is U to be exact. Then after that a group is defined : $U_n=1+p^n$ then it says $\cap_{n} U_n=1$. Why?? next how to complete the proof?

The valuation ring $R$ should consist of all elements that has non-negative values.

Yes thats why v(R) $\geq 0$.

I tried to read Frohlich's article a long time ago before I had a strong foundation in commutative algebra and algebraic number theory, and it was tough.  If it's your first time, I would highly recommend starting with a more gentle introduction to algebraic number theory, or else be willing to spend some time practicing commutative algebra on the side.
So, you've asked several different questions so I'll do my best to address in each in order.  So yes, $\pi$ is a "uniformizer," meaning an element of $R$ with valuation $1$.  I assume here that $k$ is the quotient field $R/ \mathfrak p$ and $K$ is the quotient field of $R$.  You generally just pick a uniformizer $\pi$ once and for all and work with it forever, although which one you pick doesn't matter.
Are you familiar with the field $\mathbb Q_p$ of $p$-adic numbers, and the ring $\mathbb Z_p \subset \mathbb Q_p$ of $p$-adic integers?  This is a good example to keep in mind as you're working through this section.  In fact, all the proofs carry over if you just pretend that $R = \mathbb Z_p$ and $K = \mathbb Q_p$.  For example, if $R$ is the ring $\mathbb Z_p$ of $p$-adic integers, then the prime number $p$ is the usual choice of uniformizer, and the residue field $k$ is just the finite field $\mathbb Z_p/p\mathbb Z_p = \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.
By $R\pi$, they mean the principal ideal of the ring $R$ generated by $\pi$.  By definition, this is the set of all elements of $K$ of the form $r \pi$, where $r$ is an element of $R$.  It's not difficult to see that $R\pi$ equals $\mathfrak p$, the nonzero prime ideal of $R$.  Likewise, $\mathfrak p^n = R\pi^n$ (for $n$ an integer) is the set of all elements of $K$ of the form $r \pi^n$, where $r$ is an element of $R$.
Now onto your questions:
Why the isomorphism of $k$-vector spaces $k \cong \mathfrak p^n/\mathfrak p^{n+1}$?
In general, if $I$ is an ideal of $R$, $M$ is an $R$-module, and $xm = 0$ whenever $x \in I$ and $m \in M$, then $M$ has the natural structure of an $R/I$-module: you just define $(r + I)m$ to be $rm$.
So that's what we've got here: $\mathfrak p^{n+1} \subset \mathfrak p^n$ are $R$-modules, and every element of the quotient $R$-module $\mathfrak p^n/\mathfrak p^{n+1}$ is killed by every element of $\mathfrak p$ (since, after all, $\pi \pi^n = \pi^{n+1}$), so $\mathfrak p^n/\mathfrak p^{n+1}$ is naturally a $k = R/\mathfrak p$ module.  And then you just check that the function
$$k = R/\mathfrak p \rightarrow \mathfrak p^n/\mathfrak p^{n+1}$$
$$x + \mathfrak p \mapsto x\pi^n + \mathfrak p^{n+1}$$
is a well defined bijection of sets, and is in fact an $R/\mathfrak p$-module isomorphism.
The exact sequence:
$$0 \rightarrow U \rightarrow K^{\ast} \xrightarrow{v} \mathbb Z \rightarrow 0.$$
Here $U$ is the group of units of $R$, and the map $U \rightarrow K^{\ast}$ is simply subset inclusion.  It is easy to see that $U$ is the set of elements $x$ of $K^{\ast}$ for which $v(x) = 0$, and from here the proof of the exactness of the sequence above is immediately obvious.
Why $\bigcap\limits_{n =1}^{\infty} U_n = 1$?
Here $U_n$ (for $n \geq 1$) consists of all elements of the form $1 + r \pi^n$ for some $r \in R$.  Suppose $x = 1 + r\pi^n$ is in $U_n$ is not equal to $1$.  Then since $v(r)\geq 0$, we have
$$v(x - 1) = v(r\pi^n) = v(r) + n \geq n.$$
Therefore, the only way for $x$ to be in each $U_n$ simultaneously is if $v(x-1)$ is greater than every integer.  This is impossible unless $x - 1 = 0$.

Thanks for such a clear explanation.  Actually I am going through Atiyah Macdonald also for the commutative algebra part.

You're welcome, feel free to ask more questions and I will answer
